# Iterate over javascript hash in the HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have js function which returns hash:

```
  Template.mainmenu.menuitem = function() {
    var links = {};
    links["mail"] = "http://some.net";
    links["rss"] = "http://rss.com";
    return links;
  };>
```

I want to iterate over this hash in the HTML template and create set of links.

I has tried this code:

```
<template name="mainmenu">
  {{#each menuitem}}  
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But it return nothing.  If I will change hash to array all works fine.

How can I iterate over hash and construct html links:

```
<a href="{{this.value}}">{{this.key}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what handelbars has bult-in helper for iterating over js hash, but you can write your own helper which will return content of the hash or you can to use "with":

```
{{#with links}}
  <p>{{{mail}}}</p>
  <p>{{{rss}}}</p>
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how can I write my own helper which will return content of the hash ? Sorry, but I newbie in js.

Comment: Metor natively use Handlebars template engine, so http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

As Meteor includes underscore by default, you can use underscore methods to extract contents of the hash:

```
Template.mainmenu.menuitem = function() {
    var links = {};
    links["mail"] = "http://some.net";
    links["rss"] = "http://rss.com";
    return _.values(links);
};
```

Comment: As I understand in this case I return only values of hash, but I need to have both keys and values to construct HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To continue where Hubert OG left off:

```
Template.mainmenu.menuitem = function() {
    var links = {};
    links["mail"] = "http://some.net";
    links["rss"] = "http://rss.com";
    return _.map(links, function (value, key) {return {_id: key, key: key, value: value}});
};
```

It's important to have an `_id` field as well so that Meteor's Spark rendering engine better understands what to redraw when things change.